# jQuery UI Layout - How change a pane's options and dynamically apply them without toggling the pane open/closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-layout

http://jsfiddle.net/jc3rj681/2/

Using the plugin [jQuery UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/), I have several different panes. When the user resizes the window to a small size, I would like to call a function that changes the `minsize` and `size` of the pane so that I can make it smaller with the window.

I can do this, but for the changes to apply, I must toggle closed and then toggle open the pane. This creates a lot of flickering and ends up being pretty messy looking. I only need this one pane to resize in this fashion.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way I can apply these layout changes without having to toggle the pane twice for them to apply?

Check out this **Fiddle** that I made: http://jsfiddle.net/jc3rj681/2/

In here, the changes to the "width" of the show/hide button don't get applied until you toggle the pane. If you can make this width change work without toggling, I'm sure it would solve my problem as well.

```
$("#eastToggle").click(function () {

    testLayout.toggle('east');    
});


$("#attempt").click(function () {
    testLayout.options.east.spacing_closed = 20;
    testLayout.options.east.spacing_open = 20;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a callback function or any special utility method that'll do the trick.

But you can try something like the following (probably with a resize function that'll resize the panes manually) -

```js
var testLayout = $('body').layout({
  applyDefaultStyles: true,
  east: {
    spacing_closed: 100, //toggler width
    spacing_open: 100,
    togglerLength_closed: 200, //toggler height (length)
    togglerLength_open: 200
  }
});

$("#eastToggle").click(function() {

  testLayout.toggle('east');

});


$("#attempt").click(function() {
  resize('east', 20);
});


// A function to resize the tab
function resize(region, space) {
  // Width of the new center pane
  var newCenterWidth = parseInt($('body .ui-layout-center').css('width').split('px')[0]) + testLayout.options.east.spacing_closed - space;

  // Change the options so they don't affect the layout when you expand / collapse again
  testLayout.options.east.spacing_closed = space;
  testLayout.options.east.spacing_open = space;

  // Manually resize the panes
  $('body .ui-layout-resizer-' + region).css('width', space);
  $('body .ui-layout-center').css('width', newCenterWidth);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://layout.jquery-dev.net/lib/js/jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>
<div class="ui-layout-center">Center</div>
<div class="ui-layout-north">North</div>
<div class="ui-layout-south">South</div>
<div class="ui-layout-east">East</div>
<div class="ui-layout-west">West
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <button id="eastToggle">Toggle East Panel</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button id="attempt">Change Width?</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. yeah, I think it is simplest and easiest way and prevents the flickering I have now. I will try this and see if it  works correctly with the automatically-resizing center pane