# How to trigger resize from Resizer bar in jQuery Layout programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-layout

I have a jQuery layout and I want  to trigger the mousemove and drag event of the resizer bar programmatically. There is some custom code that uses the event data of resize event resizing is done through the resizer bar.

I have tried jQuery trigger method to trigger the events and also tried changing the position of the resizer bar but resizing is not fired.

How can I trigger it?

Comment: Can you share the relevant source code with your attempt(s) please? Maybe making a minimal demo of what you are dealing with would be a good idea.

Comment: Here is some similar code: http://jsfiddle.net/sambhal/f986ckwb/6/

Comment: Your **JsFiddle** appears to be a good working demo but what changes are you trying to make? *" I want to trigger the mousemove and drag event of the resizer bar programmatically"* When are you wanting to trigger the mousemove/drag? Please explain in detail what you expect the client to do and your expected output. Thank you.

Comment: There is a scroll bar which when dragged resizes the panes, I want to trigger that resizing event without manually dragging the resizer.

Comment: Maybe this [**Stackoverflow Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688175/jquery-ui-layout-how-change-a-panes-options-and-dynamically-apply-them-withou) might be of some help?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the solution.

Comment: @NewToJS: It is not triggering the resize event.